# I am having the error: ''TemplateDoesNotExist at /seller2/'' while I open the page

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have been trying to get rid of this error:

> ''TemplateDoesNotExist at /seller2/''

while adding images to the database. I have created URL(seller2) which calls the method from views.py that is Seller2. In this method, I have taken form = ProductForm and return the HTML file. The ProductForm has been importing from forms.py which creates a form for product and its details.

```
        <urls.py>
        `from django.conf.urls import url
        from . import views
        from . import views as user_views
        from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
        from django.conf import settings
        from django.conf.urls.static import static
            
        urlpatterns = [
            url(r'^$',views.Front,name='Front'),
            url(r'^Register/$',user_views.Register,name='Register'),
            url(r'^signup_form_submitted/$',views.signup_form_submitted, name='signup_form_submitted'),
            url(r'^Login$',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='netauction/LogIn.html'), name='Login'),
            url(r'^Logout/',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='netauction/LogOut.html'), name='Logout'),
            url(r'^Home/',views.Home, name='Home'),
            url(r'^Automobiles/',views.Automobiles, name='Automobiles'),
            url(r'^Furnitures/',views.Furnitures, name='Furnitures'),
            url(r'^Musical_Instruments/',views.Musical_Instruments, name='Musical_Instruments'),
            url(r'^Home&Garden/',views.Home_Garden, name='Home_Garden'),
            url(r'^Antiques/',views.Antiques, name='Antiques'),
            url(r'^Fashion/',views.Fashion, name='Fashion'),
            url(r'^Sports/',views.Sports, name='Sports'),
            url(r'^Collection&Arts/',views.Collection_Arts, name='Collection_Arts'),
            url(r'^Seller/',views.Seller_Form,name='Seller_Form'),
            url(r'Seller/form_submitted/',views.seller_form_submitted, name='seller_form_submitted'),
            url(r'^seller2/',views.Seller2, name='Seller2')
        ]
        
        if settings.DEBUG:urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`
        
        <views.py>
        `from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
        from .models import Users
        from pip._internal import req
        from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
        from .forms import ProductForm
            
        def Seller2(request):
            form = ProductForm()
            return render(request,'seller2.html',{
                    'form': form})`
            
            
        <models.py>
        `from django.db import models
            
        class Products_Details(models.Model):
            seller = models.ForeignKey(Sellers_Details, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            product_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
            product_category = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
            product_features = models.CharField(max_length = 400)
            product_images = models.FileField(upload_to='Product_Images')
            product_starting_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
            product_current_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
            
            def __str__(self):
                return self.product_name`
        
        <forms.py>
        `from django import forms
        from .models import Products_Details
            
        class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
            class Meta:
                model = Products_Details
                fields=('seller','product_name','product_category','product_features','product_images','product_starting_price','product_current_price')`
            
            
        <settings.py>
        `TEMPLATES = [
                {
                    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
                    'DIRS': ['templates'],
                    'APP_DIRS': True,
                    'OPTIONS': {
                        'context_processors': [
                            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                            'django.template.context_processors.request',
                            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                        ],
                    },
                },
            ]`

<seller2.html>
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    {% load static %}
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href="{% static '/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href="{% static '/css/bootstrap.all.min.css' %}">
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href="{% static '/css/bootstrap.styles6.css' %}">

    <title>ONLINE AUCTION | Sellers Product Details</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        {{ form }}
    </form>
</body>
</html>`
    
    <ERROR MSG>
    `TemplateDoesNotExist at /seller2/
    seller2.html`

    <DIRECTORY PATH>
```

See the screenshots of the directory paths. I am new to this and I am having error while uploading the image directly.

[Directory Path-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPREZ.png)

[Directory Path Continues..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7ZwN.png)

Comment: Please post your directory structure. That is the only way someone can see if you have it in the right place.

Comment: @MichaelHawkins I have added the directory paths in the links. I am new to this site so i am unable to add the image directly.

Comment: Try moving your "templates" folder up a level under the "semester_project" folder. It looks like you aren't pointing to the right directory in your settings.

Answer (score 0):

What I would try first is moving your "templates" directory up a level to the "semester_project" folder, in the same level of settings.py, or even up to the same level as manage.py. So your folder structure should look something like this:

```
  semester_project >
      NetAuction (folder)
      templates (folder)
      static (folder)
      asgi.py
      settings.py
      urls.py
      ...
```

or

```
  semester_project >
      NetAuction (folder)
      asgi.py
      settings.py
      urls.py
      ...
  templates (folder)
  static (folder)
  manage.py
```

In your settings.py, you can also try making the template `DIRS` setting more generic, like so:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Your directory structure looks like it got mixed up quite a bit from what I can tell (it is hard to decipher from the images you posted though). Make sure you use the Django commands to start projects and apps like `django-admin startproject myprojectname` and `python manage.py startapp myappname`.

Also, look at the folder structure in the Django documentation and make sure you follow this when setting up projects: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/

About 90% the issues I see people report with "Template Not Found" errors in Django involves the templates folder being at the wrong level or otherwise not where it is supposed to be according to their `settings.py` file.

It also appears that your 'static' directory is the same as your 'media' directory in your settings. Static is where your CSS, JavaScript, etc. go and Media is typically where user-provided uploads and other content go.

Comment: Thanks Michael, the issue has been resolved. Perhaps, I got stuck in having two forms in single page of html using forms.py, models.py and views.py, instead i am getting only one form on screen.